# Create a Boolean Column with default value

Tags: postgresql

**BACKGROUND**

I am attempting to create a table that will have a single column and single row with boolean value. It will be either set True or False by some external application.

**CODE**

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE my_table (
  my_flag BOOL DEFAULT TRUE
);


END;


SELECT * FROM my_table
```

**ISSUE**

When i do `SELECT * FROM my_table` i expect it to return one row with the value TRUE except it returns the table and row but with no value. I am not sure why that is?

Comment: You don't insert anything into the table, so obviously the select returns no rows either

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table` => 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is empty. At least one row has to be added. Below example of creating table using CTaS:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (my_flag) AS SELECT TRUE;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d5ce6626ddf866fd0bdf0222840aee6b)**

Comment: This is actaully very neat!

Comment: Side note: can you any place where i can practice my sql skills ?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure it is not returning a row:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  my_flag BOOL DEFAULT TRUE
);

select * from my_table ;
 my_flag 
---------
(0 rows)
```

The `DEFAULT` only applies when you `INSERT` a row:

```
insert into my_table values (default);
INSERT 0 1
test(5432)=> select * from my_table ;
 my_flag 
---------
 t
(1 row)
```